# build CGAL using visual studio , cmake

Tags: visual-studio, graphics, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm trying to compile CGAL Library using visual studio on windows. I'm following the steps of this tutorial : 
https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html#BuildingCGAL

I finished configuration and generation using cmake
[image]

I stopped at the following step : *Run Visual Studio and compile ALL_BUILD project both in Debug and Release.

when I open CGAL.sln and rebuild "Allbuild" project or "install" project , it shows the following errors:
[image]

I appreciate any help , thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on project-> properties -> linker 
add C:\dev\CGAL-4.9\build\bin\Debug manually

right click on project-> properties ->c\c++ 
C:\dev\CGAL-4.9\auxiliary\mpfr\include

Answer (score 0):

You must install GMP and MPFR. If you install CGAL with the installer it is an option to download the precompiled versions of these two libraries.

Comment: the gmp & mpfr installation with cgal are failed , so I download mpfr-3.1.4 and mpfr 3.1 and linked them with MPFR_ICLUDE_DIR and GM{_INCLUDE_DIR using cmake

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly fails.